# Python - Multiple Elif Statements Being Skipped Over in If Statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my program to return different statements based off the hour the user inputs. If I input a number for hour between he first two statements ((hours < 6) and (hours <= 10) or (hours >= 6)), it will return the correct string but if I input anything greater than 10 for the hour, it won't return the intended string for that hour but it will keep repeating the second string.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's my program:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQzBi.png

```
def food(hours, boolean):

    if boolean == "True" or boolean == "true":        
        if (hours < 6):
            return "no food"

        elif (hours <= 10) or (hours >= 6):
            return "breakfast, marmalade"

        elif (hours <= 15) or (hours >= 11): 
            return "lunch, true,dessert"

        elif (hours < 22) or (hours >= 15):
            return "dinner, dessert"

        else:
            return "no food"

    else:
        if (hours < 6):
            return "no food"

        elif (hours <= 10) or (hours >= 6):
            return "breakfast,coffee"

        elif (hours <= 15) or (hours >= 11):
            return "lunch, false"

        elif (hours < 22) or (hours >= 15):
            return "dinner"

        else:
            return "no food"

x = food(15, "true")
print(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Josephi Dmitry it would be best if you show your code

Comment: @DanielMesejo my bad, just posted the link

Comment: @JosephDmitry I see but could you copy and paste the code in the question? So it can be copied?

Comment: Please don't use image sharing websites for sharing code. Paste them into the question instead.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 sorry! new to this whole thing

Comment: Note that SO isn't smart about pasting code, you usually have to manually fix indents after pasting it, which is important in Python since the whitespace matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using “and” instead of “or”. Anything > 10 will also be >= 6 so the second condition always matches.

Answer (score 1):

Python have boolean value True and False. Their is no need to use strings 'True' or 'False'. You can also use the power of if-elif-else logic. Python executes from top to bottom, when condition is met, it breaks. Your function can be rewritten to this:

```
def food(hour, boolean):
    '''Food 
    Takes in hour as int and boolean as bool
    E.g. x = food(15,True)
    # TODO:
    Ensure that input data types are correct.
    '''
    if boolean:
        if hour >= 22 or hour >= 0:
            return 'no food'
        elif hour >= 15:
            return 'dinner, dessert'
        elif hour >= 11:
            return 'lunch, true,dessert'
        elif hour >= 6:
            return 'breakfast, marmalade'
        else:
            raise ValueError('something wrong')
    else:
        if hour >= 22 or hour >= 0:
            return 'no food'
        elif hour >= 15:
            return 'dinner'
        elif hour >= 11:
            return 'lunch, false'
        elif hour >= 6:
            return 'breakfast, coffee'
        else:
            raise ValueError('something wrong')


x = food(15, True)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first elif statement is your problem. You should use and instead of or. By using or, anything >= 6 will return breakfast marmalade, not just anything between 6 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As mentioned by the other answers, using 'and' instead of 'or' would solve your issue. However, it is redundant to include more than one condition for each meal if they are all sequential as by writing:

```
if (hours < 6):
    return "no food"
```

you are already saying to only output the return value if the hour input is less than 6, hence only values more than 6 would make it to the next elif statement.

Do let me know if I misunderstood something about your program's use case that required you to write the code as such!

Comment: When doing this, be careful with the sequence of your conditions as putting `(hours < 10)` before `(hours < 6)` would break the code!